# ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate And Setting initialDelay To Date In The Past

Tags: java, timer, futuretask

I'm working on a scheduling system in Java that sends out reminders based on a *startDate*, *endDate* and *occurrence* (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, Mondays, etc). Originally I was using *Timer* and *TimerTask* classes to schedule the reminders:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(reminder, firstDate, period);
```

I recently switched to *ScheduledExecutorService* so I could have more control on cancelling events. The *ScheduledExecutorService* is working well for recurring reminders, except for the one case of rescheduling a reminder with a *startDate* in the past. The *scheduleAtFixedRate* function only allows you to specify *long* value for *initialDelay*, and not an actual *Date* object:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(reminder, initialDelay, period, unit);
```

This poses a problem, since passing in a negative *initialDelay* still causes the event to be fired immediately thus causing it to reoccur at *now* + *period*, rather than *startDate* + *period*.

Any ideas how I can (re)schedule a reminder with the *startDate* in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a quick check to see if the date is in the past, then create a new temporary start datetime that is the increment of the start past now.

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks like that will do the trick. Here's the a code snippet to calculate the initialDelay:


Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar start = reminder.getStartCalendar();
while (start.before(now)) {
   start.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int)reminder.getPeriod());
}
long initialDelay = start.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
this.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(reminder, initialDelay, reminder.getPeriod(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running it once on startup and then at the time I wanted every day:

```
// check once initial on startup
doSomething();

// and then once every day at midnight utc
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
LocalDateTime firstRun = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).atStartOfDay().plusDays(1);
Duration durationUntilStart = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC), firstRun);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        () -> doSomething(),
        durationUntilStart.getSeconds() + 1,
        Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds(),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS
);
```